# \DateTime::createFromFormat() works for a value but fails for the other one, why?

Tags: php, datetime, php-7.1

I am having a weird issue or behavior I could say regarding `\DateTime::createFromFormat()` and it's usage.

I am sending two dates from the view to my controller using AJAX. I have checked the request values (in the browser using Development Tools):

```
quote_start_date: 09/06/2017
quote_end_date: 09/19/2018
```

They are OK. I have checked the values I am getting in the function using Xdebug:

```
$request->get('quote_start_date'): ‌09/06/2017
$request->get('quote_end_date'): ‌09/19/2018
```

They are OK.

```
$quote_start_date = \DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $request->get('quote_start_date'));

\\ $quote_start_date = false

$quote_end_date   = \DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $request->get('quote_end_date'));

\\ $quote_end_date = DateTime(...)
```

I can't find what's the problem here. Can any give me a few ideas? Maybe I am missing something.

I've checked the docs [here](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) and it says:

> Returns a new DateTime instance or FALSE on failure.

But it's not too developer friendly for say what's causing the failure.

Note: I am using PHP 7.1.6.

Comment: Try to narrow down the problem. Like `var_dump( DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', '09/19/2018') );` and `var_dump( DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', '09/06/2017') );`

Comment: There is no reason that code shoudl not work, unless you have an Odd Date somewhere

Comment: Make sure the values you retrieve from the database do not contain extra invisible characters (white spaces, new lines). Take a look at this: https://3v4l.org/8Nf8M

Comment: You complain about not being developer friendly: have you tried seeing what [getLastErrors()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.getlasterrors.php) returns? Because that tells you why the date couldn't be parsed

Comment: @axiac you were right there was an empty space on the first date, using `trim()` on both values will avoid this and possible future issues with odd characters. Thank

Comment: Encountered a similar problem today with PHP7 and 8